# Finding the interior and closure of a given set, given a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

> $(\mathbb{R}, \tau): \tau=\{\emptyset\} \cup \{U \subseteq \mathbb{R}: |U^c| = n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ Is a topological space, find interior and closure of $A = [0,1)$

All sets in $\tau$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that their complement is finite.

To begin with, the closure is the intersection of all closed sets in $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$, so closed sets would be all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ because if we take the complement of that, then it would be in $\tau$.

My problem here is that I can't find a finite set (closed in the space) where $A$ is a subset since $A$ itself has infinitely many elements since it's an interval subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Similarly, I'm not quite sure where to start to find the interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U\subset A$ then $U^c\supset A^c = (-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$ which is infinite, so $U$ is not open and therefore $A^\circ = \varnothing$.

The only closed sets are finite-point sets and $\mathbb R$. Since $A$ is infinite, it follows that $\overline A=\mathbb R$.